# Get proper Device Description from Hardware ID

Tags: windows, drivers

With Windows if a driver is not installed the device will show up in Device Manager with a generic device description, for example

```
Ethernet Controller
```

instead of the proper description

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
```

when you open the properties page, you can find the Hardware ID

```
The drivers for this device are not installed.
Hardware Id
PCI\VEN_1969&DEV_2062&CC_0200
```

I am looking for a reliable way to get the proper device description from the Hardware ID. I visit [`pcidatabase.com`](http://pcidatabase.com) from time to time but I am interested in other options as well.

Comment: `lspci` from a Linux live CD is a pretty good choice. Also `lshw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you
[**search for**](http://www3.driveridentifier.com/scan/driver_file_detail.php?inf_file_id=1205687&scanid=AA32232AEBAB4E42A33BB6357B5DFF26&item_id=786901196) the `SUBSYS` value as well it can help narrow the results

```
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_9808&SUBSYS_2AE4103C
```

`driveridentifier.com` will give you a link like this

`http://www3.driveridentifier.com/scan/download_file.php?url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.hp.com%2Fpub%2Fsoftpaq%2Fsp58501-59000%2Fsp58613.exe&hardware_id=&driver_inf_file_id=1205687&scanid=AA32232AEBAB4E42A33BB6357B5DFF26`

If you click it, they want you to register. However you can [**decode the URL**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder) to get a direct link

`ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp58501-59000/sp58613.exe`